# simple form in ruby on rails- nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I am just curious about simple form and nesting. Ive read documents but still dont quite understand.

I created a website using device where a user can post tweet and also edit a tweet.
I was under the impression that [@user, @tweet] would need to be present in the simple_form_for on both new and edit forms. However i discovered that [@user, @tweet] needs to be on the new form and only [@tweet] needs to be on the edit form. is this correct?
I'm a bit unclear how this works. Is it because a new tweet needs to be assigned to a user, therefore @user and @tweet are used, and to edit a tweet, the @user isnt needed because there is no need for it?
apologies if this makes no sense.

Comment: Could you post the code of the form, controller and Tweet model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a bit unclear how this works. Is it because a new tweet needs to be assigned to a user, therefore @user and @tweet are used, and to edit a tweet, the @user isnt needed because there is no need for it?

The short answer is "yes". The longer answer is...

I don't know, but I'm guessing that the routes look something like:

```
resources :user do 
  resources :tweets, shallow: true 
end
```

Which would give you something like:

```
    user_tweets GET    /users/:user_id/tweets(.:format)          tweets#index
                POST   /users/:user_id/tweets(.:format)          tweets#create
 new_user_tweet GET    /users/:user_id/tweets/new(.:format)      tweets#new
     edit_tweet GET    /tweets/:id/edit(.:format)                tweets#edit
          tweet GET    /tweets/:id(.:format)                     tweets#show
                PATCH  /tweets/:id(.:format)                     tweets#update
                PUT    /tweets/:id(.:format)                     tweets#update
                DELETE /tweets/:id(.:format)                     tweets#destroy
          users GET    /users(.:format)                          users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)                          users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                      users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                 users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#show
                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                      users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                      users#destroy
```

So, you can see that for `tweets#edit`, `tweets#show`, `tweets#update`, and `tweets#destroy`, `:user_id` is not needed. This is due to `shallow: true`

You can read more about shallow nesting in the [guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting).

Comment: ah thanks. my code is the same as yours but i dont have shallow true.  I've actually never heard of it.

Comment: Feel free to upvote if you found the answer helpful to help future searchers.